# docker elk ( Elastic Search )connection between two composer , it is blocking requests from other servers

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have been using the - deviantony / docker-elk package .
It is a docker ELastic Search image .

well , it is working, it has a docker compose that has -

```
elasticsearch
logstash
kibana
```

So I added as well in this compose the -

```
Nginx
PHP
```

This PHP make those request to Elastic Search . it is working .
but now , this application has become bigger, and I created other docker-composer with other server to connect as well in this elastic search .

Inside the same docker-composer of the elastic search , I can make those requests .
But outside , It gives me an error -

```
cURL error 1: Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for ...
```

I tryed every thing , I created 2 docker-compose .
one for the project , other for the elastic search .

I share the network , I tryed as well to inspect the container e connect with the IP . it gives the same error .

I think , that it is not an problem of docker connection , becose it is returning this mesage of not aloud . probably elastic search block, the connection from other servers , for security .

does have any where that I can configure that ?